# Spring Boot, Demo project and Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring

I new to web development. I have a lot of question to ask.

I using spring boot for server side

1. How to use HTML & JS in front
2. How to make a AJAX call to connect JS and spring boot controller

My plan is to create a Single page application

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a tutorial site ... it's for answering specific problems you have encountered. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help. There are plenty of resources on the internet that should help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely open ended question, and breaks some of the rules of Stackoverflow. Questions should be specific, relating to a problem that your encountering, with any solutions you've tried provided.

That being said, I would recommend going through some tutorials on building a REST API with Spring Boot and doing AJAX in JavaScript.

[REST API with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

[AJAX with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)